# Forms with errors, how not to lose data in PHP

Tags: php

a little question that I hope can be answered even if I think that natively with PHP, nothing can be done.

I have a form with various input fields, obviously the frontend rules in javascript at the time of submission to report the required fields are not enough.

I have implemented a server side backend check before the form is submitted if there are any errors the form is stopped and x error alerts are displayed how many errors were encountered.

Virtually perfect.

Except that the form is made up of 200 fields and even if the user makes a mistake, boom the whole form is devoid of data.

So my question, is it possible with PHP, to display error alerts but without losing the previously written values?

code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

/*VARIABILE GLOBALE DI ERRORE*/
$error = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    /*CHECK NAME INPUT*/
    if (empty($name)) {
        $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Name is a required field</div>';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("~[0-9]+~", $name)) {
            $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> Name cannot contain numbers </div>';
        }
    }


    if (count($error) > 0) {

        /*show error with echo implode( $error);*/

    } else {
        
        /*run query*/
    }
}
?>

<?php echo implode( $error); ?>

<form  action="YOUR_PAGE.PHP" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

the goal would be to show the alerts, but without losing all the data written in the various fields that make up the form

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?php if ($error > 0) echo strip_tags($_POST['name']) ?>>
```

In this way, I display alerts and incorrect entry.

Is this the best solution?

Comment: No, there is not a native way to do this. There are many frameworks out there that would take care of this for you, however it would be a re-write. At best, find a way to optimize/map your fields for efficient array usage. I guess another way (just thinking out loud) is to create a map of JS to PHP, write POST to the PHP side of things, and then in JS loop over this map on the client side to re-fill out the form.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for taking some of your time in answering my question. But unfortunately I have no knowledge in JS and doing this for me would be like climbing a mountain. Could you read if in the additional detail to my question, under the heading (possible solution), it might be okay?

Comment: Yep, that is by far the most common way to do this. I would personally recommend wrapping that logic into a dedicated function such as `maybe_get_post_value()` that does all of your logic, probably including escaping and possibly even echoing. That will at least centralize part of it somewhere and make sure that you don't forget an `echo` or escape at some point.

Comment: Another common solution is to submit the forms using Ajax. That way you can submit the form in the background, without leaving the form at all. Then you can just return success or a list of failed fields and display the errors using JS. That way, there's no need to repopulate the form since the user will still be on the same page.